# ScrollMagic double each panel wipeAnimation dynamically

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

Ok I am going to do my best to explain the issue I am posed with. I am brand new to scrollMagic but I have done two components at this point. My issue is this site will be converted into a Wordpress theme and I need to make this dynamic so if the client adds more slides it configures the js automatically. Here is my current code and you can see its currently 7 slides but i only need to configure the 6 since the first is 0 indexed. I basically just did 100 / 6 = 16.66666667%

I need to make this automatic like 100 / num = animatePerc

I am not sure how to do this and to make sure it will be accurate. I need a little help here to even get to trying something out.

here is my code:

```
    $(function () { // wait for document ready
    // init
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();


    // define movement of panels
    var quickFacts = new TimelineMax()
        // First slide is staged in the center on page load. Second slide triggers it to slide out of window

        // animate to second panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-16.666666666666667%" })    // move in to first panel

        // animate to third panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, { delay: 1 })
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-33.3333%" })

        // animate to forth panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, { delay: 1 })
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-50%" })

        // animate to fifth panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, { delay: 1 })
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-66.66667%" })

        // animate to sixth panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, { delay: 1 })
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-83.3333%" })

        // animate to seventh panel
        .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, { delay: 1 })
        .to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: "-100%" });



    // create scene to pin and link animation
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
        triggerHook: "onLeave",

        duration: $('#content').outerHeight(true),
        reverse: true
    })
        .setPin("#pinContainer")
        .setTween(quickFacts)
        // .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
        .addTo(controller);
});
```

tying something like this right now but I am not sure how to make the transform x: dynamic. I am attempting to test on applying the width and increment:

```
var numSlides = $("section.quick-facts__panel");
    var i = 0;

    $(numSlides).each(function (index, i) {
        $(this).data('serial', i++);
        var slides = numSlides.length;
        // console.log(slides, index);
        var slideSize = 100 / slides;
        // console.log(slideSize, value);
        var slideCount = slideSize * index;
        slideCount++;
        console.log(slideCount);
        if(index !== 0)
            $(numSlides).width(slideCount);


    });
```

Comment: I added the seventh slide to push the sixth slide off the screen so... to me it feels like the animation is complete. So for right now until i get approval I want this to be how it is. It is very possible that they will want to remove that and leave the sixth slide to be centered on the page.

Comment: can you add a fiddle to demo the motion? Also can you set the x value using vars? If so, the solution would be simpler..

Comment: I think the wipeAnimation is basically what you need but to make it dynamic. I will try and work on a codepen by the end of the day here.

Comment: here's a fiddle I found of a [scrollmagic demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y5kgu7eu/5/) - might help?

Comment: please edit your question and insert your code (it's very hard to read like that) or even better put it it a runnable snippet

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull this off by doing this:

```
    $(function () { // wait for document ready
    // init
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    var numSlides = $("section.quick-facts__panel");
    var slides = numSlides.length;
    // console.log(slides, index);
    var slideSize = 100 / slides;
    // console.log(slideSize, value);
    var slideCount;


    $(numSlides).each(function (index) {
        slideCount = slideSize * index;
        // console.log(slideCount);
        $(this).css("left", slideCount + '%');

    });

    var $panels = $('#slideContainer .quick-facts__panel');
    $panels.not($panels.eq(0)).css('opacity', 0);

    // define movement of panels
    var quickFacts = new TimelineMax();

    $panels.each(function (i, item) {
        if (i === 0 || i === $panels.length) {
            return true;
        }
        quickFacts.to("#slideContainer", 1, { x: (-slideSize * i) + "%" });
        quickFacts.to($panels.eq(i), 0.25, { opacity: 1 }, "-=0.75");
    });
    // First slide is staged in the center on page load. Second slide triggers it to slide out of window

    // create scene to pin and link animation
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
        triggerHook: "onLeave",
        duration: $('#content').outerHeight(true),
        reverse: true
    })
        .setPin("#pinContainer")
        .setTween(quickFacts)
        // .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
        .addTo(controller);
});
```